# How to create unit-testing for array function in AngularJS with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have xf array: `var xf = [];`
And I have a function is a element in this array and a function to use it:

```
$scope.checkEmailValid = function () {
  var result = false;
  Iif (xf.validateEmail($scope.email, '256')) {
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
};

xf.validateUsername = function (sText) {
  var isValid = false;
  do {
    //Check for valid string.
    isValid = typeof sText === 'string';
    if (!isValid) {
      break;
    }
    //Check that each special character does not exist in string.
    for (var i = 0; i < sText.length; i++) {
      if (xf.SPECIAL_CHARS.indexOf(sText.charAt(i)) !== -1) {
        isValid = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
      break;
    }
  } while (false);
  return isValid;
};
```

But when I run my spec:

```
it ('checkEmail', function(){
  $controller('MyCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
  xf.validateUsername();
  spyOn(window,xf.validateUsername).and.callThrough();
});
```

It makes an error:

> xf.validateUsername is not a function

How can I cover it?

Comment: is `xf` a property on `$scope`, a property on the controller, or just some free-form variable in the controller function body?

Comment: @Claies: xf is just a free-form variable in the controller body.

Comment: it's not really possible to test this in that manner.  If it is not actually bound to `$scope` or exposed as a public property, it is only accessible in the function that it is defined, due to the way that JavaScript closures operate.

Answer (score 1):

The `xf` variable is not acessible from the outside of the controller's scope (i.e. not accessible in the unit test files).

You must've done the following thing:

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .controller(function ($scope) {
    var xf = [];
    // etc.
  });
```

You could attach the `xf` variable to the MyController instance once Angular instantiates it:

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .controller(function ($scope) {
    this.xf = [];
    // etc.
  });
```

But that's not really a clean way of doing it. A better way (in my opinion) would be to create a factory:

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .factory('xfService', function () {
    var xf = [];

    function validateUsername(text) {
      // etc.
    }

    function get() {
      return xf;
    }

    return {
      get: get,
      validateUsername: validateUsername
    };
  });
```

Now, you can inject the factory in your controller to use xf:

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .controller(function ($scope, xfService) {
    // somewhere
    var isValid = xfService.validateEmail($scope.email, '256');
    // to get the values in the array
    var values = xfService.get();
  });
```

Finally, for the unit tests, it becomes really easy to test the `validateEmail` method.

```
describe('Unit tests - xfService', function () {
  var xfService;
  beforeEach(angular.module('myModule'));
  beforeEach(angular.inject(function (_xfService_) {
      xfService = _xfService_;
    });
  });

  describe('xfService.validateUsername', function () {
    it('should return a boolean value', function () {
      // for example
      expect(typeof xfService.validateUsername('test')).toBe('boolean');
    });
    // add more unit tests to check that the method works as expected
  });
});
```

You'll need to add the `angular-mocks` file to the Karma config.

Thanks to Paul Podlech and Claies for the hints in the comments/answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to completely understand your question. But there are a few thinks i think you are doing wrong:

- If xf it's a global variable you should mock it, since you are testing the controller, not the global variable.
- If you want to check the real function of your global variable, go to the `karma.conf.js` file and add the js file path to the `files` option:

  `files: [
     ...,
     'fx-script.js',
     ...
  ],`
- [`callThrough`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E) should be used before the actual function is invoked:

  `it ('checkEmail', function(){ 
    var ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
    spyOn(window, ctrl.xf.validateUsername).and.callThrough();
    ctrl.xf.validateUsername();
  });`

I recommend you to separately test your `controller`, `service`, or global scripts, and add mocks whenever you need to inject a dependency or global variable, so if you can tell for sure which `module`/`script` is failing any time.

Comment: Hi @Matho. Yes, I'm testing controller. xf is local variable in this controller. `var xf = [ ]`. And function `validateUsername()` is in together in file with xf array.
I've written your code, but it's make error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateUsername' of undefined`

Comment: In that case the problem is that you should do is expose the `validateUsername` function in the `ctrl.scope` just like you are doing it with `$scope.checkEmailValid`.
You can and should only test the public functions which are exposed by the controller.
_Example:_ If your controller haves a `function A`, `function B` in their scope, and the B function calls the `function C`, in that case you should test A and B and see the spected results.

Answer (score 0):

you should move functionality in xf into separate service/factory. Then inject it in controller. That makes it pretty easy to mock it while testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the controller

```
var xf = this.xf = [];
```

and this in your test

```
it ('checkEmail', function(){
 var xf = $controller('MyCtrl', { $scope: $scope }).xf;
 spyOn(xf, 'validateUsername').and.callThrough();
 xf.validateUsername();
});
```

But you should realize that this exposes your xf object on the Controller as mentioned in the comment of [Claies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743717/how-to-create-unit-testing-for-array-function-in-angularjs-with-jasmine#comment51511986_31743717).